# Deciphering keyboard shortcuts in pharo 3

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Using Pharo 3 on windows, if I right click a selector in the browser, I see a menu item that says:

Senders of...    b,n

Is this describing a keyboard shortcut? What key combination do I press to show the senders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As they say [here](http://pharo.gemtalksystems.com/book/Tidbits/KeyboardShortcuts/), you use <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd> in Mac or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd> in human-beings' computers :)

In this particular case, as they say in [this thread](http://forum.world.st/Pharo-3-shortcuts-td4747014.html), it's a multi-step shortcut: you first <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>, and then <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth mentioning some useful navigation shortcuts:

ALT+Tab (cycle between open windows)
Shift+Enter - global search